# How to assign a file content to the variable?

Tags: windows, if-statement, for-loop, batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
SET str1=type %1
SET str2=type %2
echo File1: %str1%
echo 
echo File2: %str2%
```

You probably know what I want but the command line interpreter doesn't. How to do it properly?

**PS.** I mean the whole content, not only the first line!

Comment: Do you mean read a variable from a file?

Comment: You can put the content line by line in a set of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the content (all lines):

```
@echo off &setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "files=1"
if "%~1"=="" set "files="
if "%~2"=="" set "files="
if not defined files echo Missing filename(s^).&goto:eof
:: read the first file
set /a cnt1=0
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("%~1") do set /a cnt1+=1 &set "str1!cnt1!=%%i"
:: read the second file
set /a cnt2=0
for /f "usebackqdelims=" %%i in ("%~2") do set /a cnt2+=1 &set "str2!cnt2!=%%i"
:: write the first file
echo File1:
for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt1%) do echo !str1%%i!
:: write the second file
echo File2:
for /l %%i in (1,1,%cnt2%) do echo !str2%%i!
endlocal
```

Comment: I made an edit concerning the "content".

Comment: What is the difference between `%1` and `%~1`?

Comment: The `~` parameter does remove surrounding double quotes.